# How to decode a live stream encoded using FFMPEG?

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg

I am not very proficient with C programming and working on live streaming using FFMPEG. Basically, I want to put a watermark on a live streaming video.

Using FFMPEG, I have been able to record a video from webcam, encode it and send to some ip:port using UDP. Now, my receiver(written in Java) is receiving the data in packets but I don't know how to decode it for editing or play it. If I use ffplay, it plays it automatically. I referred some links: 
[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172878/how-to-open-file-live-stream-with-ffmpeg-edit-each-frame-with-opencv-and-save-th) 
[Decoding Encoding Example](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/decoding__encoding_8c-source.html)

Could anyone please tell, how can I proceed for the solution. Any hints would be appreciable.

1. How the data is encoded. Is it some FFMPEG format or generic format?
2. If a live stream is coming, then what information does each packet contains? Whether it is a complete video itself or a portion of complete video file?

Comment: The data is encoded in whatever format you chose to encode it with in FFmpeg.  How are you executing FFmpeg?  Are you just executing the binary and using pipes, or are you using libffmpeg?

Comment: I am using 'ffmpeg-20160425-git-9ac154d-win32-shared' with default configuration using commands:  
  
`ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="USB Video Device":audio="Microphone (USB Audio Device)" -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:7000`  
  and  
`ffmpeg -re -i "C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.wmv"  -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:7000`

Comment: And, what does the FFmpeg output say for video codec?  MPEG-2?  I don't know what the default is for MPEG-TS off the top of my head, but the STDERR output of FFmpeg will tell you what you need to know.  And, why are you outputting with a codec anyway?  What you need are the raw frames.  Have you considered just letting FFmpeg do this watermarking for you?

Comment: I also used `ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="USB Video Device":audio="Microphone (USB Audio Device)" -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -b 900k -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:7000`. Options were given on some website. BUt, I couldn't understand the output. Whether it is portion of single file or multiple files. In live streaming, how the data is transmitted?

Comment: I haevn't tried the watermarking with FFMPEG yet. Will check if there is anything possible with FFMPEG. Any other way to capture raw frames from a live stream?

Comment: Whether you eventually live stream this or not is irrelevant.  You need to use FFmpeg to get the raw frames to your application.  Otherwise you're wasting a ton of CPU and losing quality by encoding, just to turn around and decode again.  Use `-pix_fmt rgb24` or similar.  Since you're connecting on localhost, I also recommend just using normal pipes to handle the output of FFmpeg.

Comment: OK..I will check with these options...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Integrated Webcam" -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -window_size qcif -f sdl "SDL output"
```

this FFMPEG command works for me on windows.

Comment: Maybe you can give a brief explanation of your code, and also answer his other two questions...